# raw converter in geeqie

Tags: linux, jpeg, photos

I need to make batch conversion for my RAW Canon CR2 pictures to JPEG format.
I can use ufraw, but aprox. half pictures needs different adjustment (automatic OR Standard).

BUT when I viewing RAW files in my favourite application **geeqie** all pictures are displayed **absolutely perfect**!

Geeqie has no export to jpeg and I'm not able get information about RAW converter used in geeqie.
Any idea how to use Geeqie or her library to conversion?

*PS. Excuse me, Stackoverflow forbidden me insert these relevant tags: raw, canon, geeqie, ufraw, jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually geeqie has no RAW converter. It actually does a little dirty trick - it displays the JPEG file embedded within the RAW file.

So, you need another program for converting RAW files. I cannot recommend any unfortunately, but there are lots of options for Linux.

You can also extract the embedded JPEG files from the RAW files with exiftool:

The below script extracts the embedded JPEG from all RAW files in a directory:

```
for f in `ls` ; do echo "File: $f" ; exiftool -b -JpgFromRaw $f > $f.jpg ; done
```

A longer explanation is at http://photophindings.blogspot.ro/2013/05/how-do-i-extract-embedded-jpeg-from-raw.html

Comment: Thanks! This is great resolving of my mystery. Who can make better  conversion from the RAW file then the source camera?
exiftool works perfect, for Canon CR2 format with these parameters: 

exiftool -b -PreviewImage source.CR2 > previw.jpg